# Mouse click with linux device tree

Tags: raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, mouse

I am working on a project with a raspberry pi controller.  There are 6 buttons that I utilize to initiate a mouse click through pynput and RPi.GPIO.  These are industrial buttons though, and I have been unable to manage the bounce through RPi bouncetime setting.

I have had success with a mechanical keypad which uses a device tree overlay to simulate keyboard keys (0-9).

I am a novice in device tree mechanics.  Is it possible to simulate a mouse click at a certain location using the linux device tree overlay?  I know the answer is probably yes, but does anyone know of any sample code that could accomplish this?

Comment: Read about `gpio-keys` kernel driver, no need to use some custom code (RPi.GPIO).